# SQL - Cross-Join in c#

Tags: c#, sql, cross-join

Im currently having a problem, because the time my operations take, are to long!

I have two tables in my sql.

```
- Users
- Objects
```

There are access rights, which can be calculated with a function `dbo.AccessRight(objId, userId)`.

In my C# Code, i need all objects with a list of users. For example:

```
*Object 1*: Id, Name, AnyPropertie, List<User>
```

To achieve this, im currently getting all objects, iterating over them and adding all users, smth like this:

```
foreach (var o in Objects)
{
    o.Users = GetAllUsersWithAccess(o.Id);
}
```

How can I realize it without looping through it? It currently took about 5 Minutes for 60k Objects.

Edit 1:

Code for GetAllUsersWithAccess:

```
public HashSet<long> GetAllUsersWithAccess(long id)
{
    var results = new HashSet<long>(Database.SqlQuery<long>("use database; select Id from dbo.Users where dbo.AccessRight(@p0, Id) > 0;", id));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of `GetAllUsersWithAccess`? and the model classes. Are you using EF? How are you getting the data of the `Objects`?

Comment: Theoretically speaking ORM should solve these issues

Comment: @GiladGreen Added the code snipper. Im using EF. Im getting the objects via DbSet. Btw. im using code-first.

Comment: I suspect it's the `dbo.AccessRight(@p0, Id) > 0;` that's costing you a lot of performance

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I think you're right. The operation itself doesn't take really long, but its the iteration through it. So if someone has a solution how to eliminate the need to loop, it would be awesome!

Comment: What does it do? If possible, rewrite it to simple / non-function SQL and the database should be much happier :)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The function is using a DLL which can evaluate all groups and users, if they have access to a specific object. I think rewriting is not an option.

Comment: When the function is that complex, I think you'd might be better off mixing your approach and instead of extracting "correct" users, then extract all users from the database and then running the function in code, and then use a caching approach.